# Return not working in action method ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, return

I know this may sound weird but something is wrong with my code.

Here is my action method:

```
[Route("{id:int}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DeleteServicePrice(int id) 
{
    var sp = await _db.ServicePrices.FindAsync(id);

    if (sp == null)
        return NotFoundResponse();

    _db.ServicePrices.Remove(sp);

    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return NoContentResponse();
}
```

And these are my helper methods from `BaseApiController`:

```
protected HttpResponseMessage NotFoundResponse(string message = null) {
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new { message = message ?? ResponseMessages.TheRequestedContentWasNotFound });
}

protected HttpResponseMessage NoContentResponse(string message = null) {
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, new { message = message ?? ResponseMessages.TheDeletionRequestWasSuccessfullyCompleted });
}
```

As you can see, if `sp == null` I return `NotFoundResponse()` which returns a 404 status code.

But when I send a `DELETE` Http request, everything works and that record gets deleted from database but I get 404 which is not what I expect.

I suspect there's a problem in the way I use `async-await` keywords.

In other words, `sp` is `NULL` at first and if block gets executed but it goes down more, to delete `sp` and this time it isn't null and the delete operation works.

Comment: You debugged your code and seen what is happening (or not happening)?

Comment: @Ralf - When I debug the code everything works as expected and I get ```204``` status code at the end. The behavior I mentioned in the question just happens on the server.

Comment: You seem to be using a very, very old version of ASP.NET Web API - have you considered upgrading to something _not_ last updated almost 10 years ago?

Comment: HTTP 204 `No Content` **requires** a zero-length response body - but your `NoContentResponse` method seems to return a string message `ResponseMessages.TheDeletionRequestWasSuccessfullyCompleted` to ASP.NET to render as the response - you should fix that by either changing it to HTTP 200 - or removing the response message with 204. See here: https://github.com/httpwg/http-core/issues/26

Comment: @Dai - You're right, I'm using ASP.NET WebApi v5.2.9 and I know its too old. But this is what it is, I live in a third world country and I can't afford to buy new hardware to use latest version of software.

Comment: When you haven't debugged it in the "problematic" environment can you be sure that the method hasn't been executed twice? Your description would fit that.

Comment: @Dai - I confirm that removing the message from ```NoContentResponse``` method fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: @Hooman Upgrading to ASP.NET Core does not require hardware upgrades - it's all software. I'm still running 15+ year-old hardware in a rack somewhere, in-fact.